# Close Menu With a Click on body with event listener & parentnode

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to close the re-sized menu when one clicks anywhere on the page. I've searched various stack overflow answers but haven't found one that does not interfere with the menu code itself, my menu...

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //open-close submenu on mobile
  $('.cd-main-nav').on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is('.cd-main-nav'))
      $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('is-visible0');
  });
  //i have tried adding this but hasn't worked
  $('html').click(function() {
    if ($('.cd-main-nav').children('ul').hasClass('is-visible0')) $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('is-visible0');

  });
});
```

Comment: `$(document).on('click', function(){//YOUR_CODE})` and use `stoppropagation` on _resized_ menu..

Comment: what this tagged tag is `j`?

Comment: yea feels like a duplicate now :/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('html').click(function() {
     //Hide the menus if visible
});
```

Include this code as it detects click anywhere on the html page
also to ensure the html doesnt fire when you click the element you intend to

```
$('.cd-main-nav').on('click', function(event) {
event.stopPropagation();
// rest of your code here
});
```

Comment: thanks but not working, tried.. `$('html').click(function() {

  if($('.cd-main-nav').children('ul').hasClass('is-visible0')) $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('is-visible0');
  
 });`

Comment: what error are you getting in your browser console?

Comment: no error just not working

Comment: If no error have you tried putting the code outside `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {});`

Comment: yeah i have still nothing

Comment: can you give your full code? html and js

Comment: i posted it here [click question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35968698/close-menu-onbody-click-and-animate-body/35968837#35968837)